# JQuery Clone div while removing internal img div src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code here in the I am cloning the div. Now up to cloning, it is fine. Now there is img tag inside this cloned div which sets image src on uploading now if I go to click add new then it clones the div and also the image with preview because I have img tag inside that I want the same thing inside div or outside but at the same location. any thoughts? Also, there is one more thing when I upload image after cloning new div there is a mistake u will see all the working just run the snippet.

here goes my code

```js
$(".file-input-area").click(function() {
  $("#file-upload").click();


});


$('#copy-button').click(function() {
  var target = $('.clone-element:last');
  target.clone(true, true).insertAfter(target);
});

function readURL(input) {

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#uploaded-image').attr('src', e.target.result).css({
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '120px'
      });

    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#file-upload").change(function() {
  $(".file-input-area").hide();
  $(".uploaded-image-div").show();
  readURL(this);
});
```

```css
.file-input-area {
  background: #e9e8e8;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: #263238 dashed 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 92px;
  color: #e6294b;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row clone-element">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Upload Image</label>
      <input type="file" id="file-upload" style="display:none !important;" />

      <div class="file-input-area">

        <h3> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> &nbsp;Upload File </h3>
        <span class="input-project1"> choose</span> to choose file.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uploaded-image-div" style="display:none;">
      <img src="#" id="uploaded-image" alt="uploaded-image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Description</label>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your message here"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="copy-button" title="add new image and desciption" value="New image + Desc">
```

Comment: What should happen when you simple run code, create clone and upload image in original "upload File" view? Should it also appear into clone "Upload file" view ? Or do nothing ?

Comment: upload file should show but not the image inside it. The image is displayed only when upload div is clicked. The image is repeating when add button is clicked i Don't want image to clone only the div . any solution

Comment: This issue is happening because of same id of elements. In this can instead of using id in jquery you should use parent, child & siblings relation to find element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate the click event "$("body").on("click", ".file-input-area", function () {" so that click will work with dynamically created element and added code to set attribute 'src' to '#'.

```js
    $().ready(function () {
        var objThis;
        $("body").on("click", ".file-input-area", function () {
            objThis = $(this).parents('.clone-element');
            $("#file-upload").click();
        });


        $('#copy-button').click(function () {
            var target = $('.clone-element:last');
            var cloneElement = target.clone();
            cloneElement.find('img').attr('src', '#');
            cloneElement.find('textarea').val('');
            cloneElement.find(".file-input-area").show();
            cloneElement.find(".uploaded-image-div").hide();

            cloneElement.insertAfter(target);
        });

        function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    objThis.find('#uploaded-image').attr('src', e.target.result).css({
                        'width': '100%',
                        'height': '120px'
                    });
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        $("#file-upload").change(function () {
            objThis.find(".file-input-area").hide();
            objThis.find(".uploaded-image-div").show();
            readURL(this);
        });
    });
```

```css
.file-input-area {
            background: #e9e8e8;
            padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: #263238 dashed 1px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            text-align: center;
            height: 92px;
            color: #e6294b;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 10px;
        }
```

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="row clone-element">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Upload Image</label>
                <input type="file" id="file-upload" style="display:none !important;" />

                <div class="file-input-area">

                    <h3> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> &nbsp;Upload File </h3>
                    <span class="input-project1"> choose</span> to choose file.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uploaded-image-div" style="display:none;">
                <img src="#" id="uploaded-image" alt="uploaded-image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Description</label>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your message here"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="copy-button" title="add new image and desciption" value="New image + Desc">
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code. I have done changes in html and javascript.

When you use something like cloning and have multiple items, you should avoid to use id. Use class name and parent, child, sibling relationship to find elements.

```js
$(".file-input-area").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".file-upload").click();


});


$('#copy-button').click(function() {
  var target = $('.clone-element:last');
  target.clone(true, true).insertAfter(target);
});

function readURL(input) {
  var fileUpload = input;
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $(fileUpload).parent().parent().find('.uploaded-image').attr('src', e.target.result).css({
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '120px'
      });

    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$(".file-upload").change(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".file-input-area").hide();
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".uploaded-image-div").show();
  readURL(this);
});
```

```css
.file-input-area {
  background: #e9e8e8;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: #263238 dashed 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 92px;
  color: #e6294b;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row clone-element">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Upload Image</label>
      <!-- Added file-upload class -->
      <input type="file" id="file-upload" class="file-upload" style="display:none !important;" />

      <div class="file-input-area">

        <h3> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> &nbsp;Upload File </h3>
        <span class="input-project1"> choose</span> to choose file.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uploaded-image-div" style="display:none;">
      <!-- Added uploaded-image class -->
      <img src="#" id="uploaded-image" class="uploaded-image" alt="uploaded-image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Description</label>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your message here"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="copy-button" title="add new image and desciption" value="New image + Desc">
```